# IEnumerator vs IEnumerator<T>

Tags: c#

I'm fairly new to c sharp and was looking for an answer to the following:

Why would you want to implement `IEnumerator<T>` when you have `IEnumerator`? `IEnumerator` returns back the item from the collection as type object, so caters for all types.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to SO.  **Please do not ask two questions in one question**. If you have two questions then post two questions.

Comment: Yeah you're right, i'll remove the second question from this one. cheers

Comment: With `IEnumerator<T>` you get type safety. ie. you don't need to check the type of the object before you use it since you know it is of type T

Comment: Generics are always more efficient because it avoids the need to box and unbox values.

Comment: I see no reason to downvote this question; though it is a beginner question its perfectly clear and the semantics of generics are often not obvious to the beginner.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> [The non-genericized] `IEnumerator` returns back the item from the collection as type object, so caters for all types.

That's exactly the problem. You now know *nothing* about the objects that are in the sequence. They could be *anything* and so you have to be able to deal with *anything* coming out of that sequence. If you have a sequence of giraffes, or a sequence of customers, or a sequence of integers, then you know that every element in the sequence will be a giraffe, customer, integer, whatever.  If you have a sequence of objects then you have to write code that checks what kind of thing each of those objects is.

Having type information enables the compiler to thread that information through the system.  Suppose we have an `IEnumerable<Customer>`.  So everything in the sequence is a customer. If we then say:

```
var first = customers.First();
var address = first.Address;
```

Now the compiler can deduce that `first` is a `Customer`, and know that customers have addresses, and so the second line is legal. If `customers` were just `IEnumerable` then the compiler cannot prove that your program is typesafe!

Also, some types exhibit a performance penalty called the "boxing penalty" when treated as `object`.  Having a generically-typed collection eliminates that penalty.

Comment: Brilliant mate. Thank you so much for the response.